# Jsonp request return missing ; SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest, jsonp

i try this code

```
<body>
<script>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://www.viaggiatreno.it/viaggiatrenonew/resteasy/viaggiatreno/statistiche/1403508155490",
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(result);
    }
});                    

</script>
```

but the response is ** SyntaxError: missing ; before statement**

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url that you are requesting returns the text:

```
{"treniGiorno":2843,"ultimoAggiornamento":1403513918086,"treniCircolanti":524}
```

The correct returned text should be:

```
jsonCallback({"treniGiorno":2843,"ultimoAggiornamento":1403513918086,"treniCircolanti":524});
```

Also consider adding the jsonpCallback parameter to your ajax query, like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    url: "http://www.viaggiatreno.it/viaggiatrenonew/resteasy/viaggiatreno/statistiche/1403508155490",
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: in witch way i can do that?

Comment: You have to do it in the server side: the url that you are requesting, if you are unable to modify that on the server, then you should ask the developers if there is a parameter that you can pass in the query string to make it to return the text in jsonp format. Otherwise is impossible to make the request as jsonp

Comment: I cannot modify a server side and if i add "jsonpCAllback"  i continue receive the same error...

Comment: If you cant modify the server side, then there no means to make a jsonp request if the server is not returning jsonp format, please read about jsonp concepts...

Comment: ok , but if i do dataType:"json" jquery return OK 200 success but don't do anything

Comment: which is the domain from where the javascript ajax call is executed? you can't make a simple json call to a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is because string returned in response is not a valid `jsonp` format. You may want to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).